# How to destroy a dialog fragment completely for memory leak issue?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I Have a empty dialog fragment. For get memory leak issue, I Add **LeakCanary** library to my app. When open dialog fragment with this commands:

```
DialogFragment fragment = TabsFragment.newInstance();
fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.DialogFragments);
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyFragment");
```

and close it, LeakCanary show me this Error:

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8CGs.jpg)

I try and add *setRetainInstance* in **OnCreate** method and *view = null* in **onDestroyView**. But that memory leak error still showing.

This is my Fragment:

```
public class TabsFragment extends DialogFragment {

private View view;

public static TabsFragment newInstance() {
    return new TabsFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    dismiss();
    view = null;
}
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open dialog like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(TabsFragment.newInstance(), "Fragment");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

And in onDismiss method in your dialog fragment, Write this codes:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, my bro! I use this way and I don't have any error for a memory leak.